# Share RestTemplate's MessageConverters across multiple instances

Tags: java, multithreading, resttemplate

Benchmarks I made showed that about 70% of the time for creating a `new RestTamplate()` is the `MessageConverters`, So I wondered if it's safe to create one set of converters and to use it across multiple instances, from different threads.

**EDIT:**
The motivation was logging "on the wire" all traffic. I thought about implementing it using a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`. but since each request should be logged to a different file, I thought to create new RestTemplate to each set of requests, with a different Interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

This javadoc of [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) doesn't explicitly require it, but the intention is for implementations to be thread safe. If they are thread safe, they are then safe to use across multiple `RestTemplate` instances.

---

`RestTemplate` is a like any other HTTP client you would use. You shouldn't typically need more than one instance per application. (Some exceptions exist for proxies, SSL configurations, etc.)

Comment: This is the most efficient way I can figure to log "on the wire" responses from the server where using `RestTemplate`